# How to unify validation across layers/tiers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, n-tier-architecture

In a typical MVC application we have validation that occurs in many different places.  It might be client-side, in the controller, and then again at the data level.  If you have a business layer, then there is additional validation there as well.

How do we unify all these so that we're not violating DRY, and causing support nightmares when validations change?  A sub-question is how to enable dynamic validation based on the model across all layers.

For example:  We may have a ViewModel that has data annotation attributes.  In MVC2/3 this unifies client-side and controller validation, but does not help with the data model (unless you are using your data model as your view model, which isn't a good practice).

This means you have to add the same validations to the data model and business layers, duplicating it.  What's more, the data model might have subtly different validation requirements than the view model (for instance, an entire data record might comprise several view models of a multi-step wizard.  And only a complete record can be saved).

Some people add complex validation to the data model when using an ORM like EF or L2S with partial classes, which i'm not sure is the right path either.  It works for apps that are primarily data oriented (data entry type apps), but would not work for apps that have more non-data business logic.

What I'd like is some way to either generate validation for all layers, or a way to hook into a single validation system.  Does anything like that exist?

Comment: Maybe there should be something like Automapper for translating validation rules between layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I really don't understand your answer since rarely is your data model, business model, and view model all the same.  If they are, just use the data model and put the validation on it.  The validations across all your layers are specific to the layer.

Example: Your ui should not contain business layer logic in case you ever change the ui layer, or create a new one.

Comment: The UI often *DOES* have to contain business logic.  For instance, validating that a field is within two parameters.  If you only put this validation in the data model, then you have to round trip to get the error.  If you put it only in the UI, then you risk someone putting bad values in server side.  There are *many* kinds of business logic that span all layers, particularly when you take client-side validation into account.

Answer (score 1):

"Fluent Validation" provides better re-usability.
Please visit.
http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Re-usable documents for Fluent Validation.

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#ReusingValidators

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Collections

Below one may be full fill your needs.
http://tnvalidate.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does Fluent Validation deal with client-side validation as well?  It's not difficult to write validation that is solely server side.

Comment: Please refer http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does that have to do with Fluent Validation?  That's talking about Custom validation attributes.  If you have to createa custom validation attribute to handle client side, then use Fluent Validate server side, what's the point?